# Shared libraries not found on other system

Tags: c++

I am compiling game on ubuntu (with installed liblaries glfw glew sfml) and game is working correctly, but when i copy excutable to other ubuntu machine and try to run it i am getting errors:

```
    libsfml-audio.so.2.4 => not found
    libGLEW.so.2.0 => not found
    libglfw.so.3 => not found
```

why?
(I am using code::blocks and gnu gcc compilator , ubuntu 18.04)

Comment: Are the installed libraries the correct versions?

Comment: Does the other machine have those libraries installed on it?

Comment: when i install sfml apt-get install libsfml-dev
i am still getting that sfml is not found

Comment: If the second computer is running the program and not building it, you should not need the dev libraries. The regular ones should do.

Comment: Did you install the correct version of the library?

Comment: there is only  apt-get install libsfml2.3 i need 2.4 what should i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dynamically linking to the libraries you use.  That means that when you compile your program, the compiler doesn't insert the code for the glfw, glew, or sfml functions you call into your binary.  Instead, those functions will be looked up in the appropriate dynamic library when you run the program.

What that means is that the dynamic libraries "libsfml-audio.so.2.4", "libGLEW.so.2.0", and "libglfw.so.3" have to be installed on the computer you run the program on as well as the computer you compile the program on.

If you don't want to install the libraries you use on the computer you run the program on or they aren't available on that computer then you will need to statically link those libraries.  That way the compiler will copy all of the code for the library functions you call into your binary and it can run without the dynamic libraries being present.  This will increase the size of your binary somewhat, and some libraries (like the GNU C standard library) either aren't possible to link to statically or don't work well when you do.  For this reason it's generally a good idea to build your program on the oldest distribution you want it to be able to run on.

Alternatively you could distribute your program as source code and have users compile it themselves for their system.

Answer (score 0):

your executable loads external code when it starts up via 'shared libraries' or .so files. These can live anywhere on the system and are loaded using various path rules. (windows equivalent is the dll)

`ldd` is a unix utility to show you these dependencies.

One option might be to compile these libraries directly into your code if a static (.a) version exists.

Another is just to bundle them together. the default loading rule is to check for an .so in the current directory before exploring the path IIRC.